# QNetworkProxy: unset proxy

Tags: python, proxy, pyqt, qnetworkaccessmanager

How to unset the proxy settings in python set by `QNetworkProxy.setApplicationProxy`?

Sultan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To go back to the application defaults, use

```
QNetworkProxy.setApplicationProxy(QNetworkProxy(QNetworkProxy.DefaultProxy))
```

if you want to explicitly disable any proxy you can use `QNetworkProxy.NoProxy` instead.